# Issues verifying that JAVA_HOME is set as expected

Tags: java, variables, environment

relieved and grateful to find this community you have made and keep it up!
I installed JDK on my laptop, it is JDK20 on OS X Ventura 13.4.1 on ARM64

```
java version "20.0.2" 2023-07-18
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 20.0.2+9-78)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0.2+9-78, mixed mode, sharing)
```

I added JAVA_HOME to my terminal's environment variable this way:
`nano ~/.zshrc`

copy pasted this:
`export /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-20.jdk/Contents/Home`

saved it
then I tried to check that its actually added it as expected based on what I added to the env var this way:
`echo $JAVA_HOME`

instead of seeing the path, I just see a blank line.
I've looked it up and tried a few recommended steps, no luck so far,
While you are replying I will keep trying to find a fix on my end and update this.

I tried looking it up, I tried checking that I spelled the export path correctly, I checked that there were no unexpected spaces, I saved the file, I retried and I am still getting the same blank line. I think I am expected to know this because when one installs the JDK on your workstation you are expected to know that you have done so correctly so it works as expected.

Comment: Use `/usr/libexec/java_home -V` to see what's installed; use `export JAVA_HOME=/path/to/…` to set `$JAVA_HOME`.

Comment: Did you restart your terminal? The file is only re-read when the shell is started again. You might also want to double-check that you’re running `zsh` as your shell. Try `echo $SHELL`. It’s `zsh` by default on recent macOS versions, but if you migrated from an earlier version it might be `bash`. In that case, you should add the setting to `.bashrc` instead.

Comment: It's `export JAVA_HOME=/Library/all that other stuff`. Then, follow the other advice (such as restarting zsh).